# “No accounts with iTunes connect access iTunes connect access for” facing error at upload time

Tags: ios, iphone

“No accounts with iTunes connect access"
iTunes connect access for "account name" is required. Add a account in the accounts preference pane.

Comment: So what don't you understand from this message?

Comment: I m already login with my account and many times uploaded using same account but suddenly getting above error.

Answer (score 0):

The Apple ID which you are using to upload the app that Apple ID must be connected to both i.e. iTunesConnect portal and Developer portal with the minimum roles given below:-

> Developer: Admin
>
> iTunesConnect: Admin/Technical

Comment: All set !! many times uploaded successfully using same account.

Comment: From which mode you are uploading, i.e. by making an archive and uploading via application loader or by Fastlane?

Comment: using Fast-lane to upload.

Comment: Try to delete the Fastlane folder or please recheck your Appfile, here is mine one:- https://prnt.sc/gmkj7m.
Also please update your Fastlane, sometimes it works.

Answer (score 0):

i resolve the question after update to xcode 9.0
hope this can help you.